# cross-debugging using VS2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have a function that is supposed to work the same when launched from some part of my program or from some other part, but it doesn't. 
Is there a method of debugging to see the difference in the execution?
What I am doing right now is launch 2 instances of VS2008 and launch the debugger on 2 instances of  my program, and execute each function from different method. I have the same breakpoints so I can compare "step by step" what is different but this is very long and tedious...
Is there a better/automated way to do this? thanks
(this is unmanaged C++)

Comment: If you want to trace the execution of both programs from within the same debugger go to the "Debug" menu and select "attach to process"

Answer (score 0):

The answer of this question should help you:
[How to debug in visual studio 2008 express c# this senario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922898/how-to-debug-in-visual-studio-2008-express-c-sharp-this-senario/7923360#7923360) There is a C# tag, but the same thing can be done in C++. Only the algorithm is explained with no code. That's my personal favourite algorithm for debugging.